# How to replace MongoDB records that have a BSON UTCDateTime?

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB version 3.4.17, accessed via PHP (MongoDB PHP API version 1.4). When the server writes a JSON document to the database, it first adds a timestamp field like so:

```
$record['date_modified'] = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime();
```

When reloading this record, which is serialized into a JSON, used by JavaScript, then passed back to the server to be saved with collection->replaceOne(), I get this error:

```
invalid argument for replace: keys cannot begin with "$": "$date""
```

The JavaScript console shows the date as an object with multiple levels of child objects:

```
date_modified:
   $date:
       $numberLong: "1572318771000"
```

Questions:

1. What should I be doing differently so I can save the JSON back to the database without it throwing the error it does for 'keys cannot begin with "$"?
2. It would be handy for JavaScript to have the date in a more useful format. Like maybe a string that the JavaScript Date() method could take in its constructor. Should I be using [one of these methods](http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) on the server side to convert it?

Comment: Why do you serialize the command into JSON? You can insert/update directly with php.

Comment: JavaScript is requesting the JSON document from the PHP-based server. So JavaScript needs the document as JSON. JavaScript then makes changes and sends it back to the server to update that document.

Answer (score 1):

How do you insert the data and how do you retrieve it?

I use this, and it works fine:

```
use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime;
$doc = [
    "input" => $input,
    "host" => gethostname(),
    "timestamp" => new UTCDateTime(NULL),
];
$ret = $logging->insertOne($doc);
```

In order to convert a Mongo BSON date back to PHP Date, use [MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime::toDateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.todatetime.php)

If you need to work with JSON strings, then these commands would be useful:

```
use function MongoDB\BSON\toRelaxedExtendedJSON;
use function MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP;
use function MongoDB\BSON\toPHP;
use function MongoDB\BSON\fromJSON;
```

Here is an example how they could be used:

```
$match = []; 
$match["dp"] = 123; 

$find_time = []; 
$find_time["t0"] = ['$lte' => new UTCDateTime($value)];

$pipeline = []; 
array_push($pipeline, array('$match' => $find_time) ); 

$json = []; 
array_push($json, '{ "$unset": ["h", "sp", "tdp", "tdi"] }');
array_push($json, toRelaxedExtendedJSON(fromPHP(array('$match' => $match)))); 
foreach ($json as $stage) {
    array_push($pipeline, toPHP(fromJSON($stage)));
}

foreach ($collection->aggregate($pipeline, array('allowDiskUse' => true)) as $row) {
    array_push($ret, self::MongoToArray($row));
}
```

Comment: I'm using replaceOne() to write to the database. Put simply, I'm looking to load a JSON from mongoDB to be used in JavaScript, possibly modified by JavaScript, then saved back into the database. So it doesn't sound like the fromPHP / toPHP functions are what I'm after. I simply need the JSON I loaded to be able to be written back without errors.

Comment: Maybe provide a sample JSON document you like to load into MongoDB. Actually MongoDB does not accept anything else than JSON (to certain extend), so I wonder why it should generate any problem at all.

Comment: Here's an example JSON:

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d09879c0f0d08f41700002e"
    },
    "id": "T000831",
    "status": 2,
    "date_modified": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1613591538000"
        }
    }
}

Comment: Note that the date_modified field is the result of a findOne() query when the date_modified saved was a UTCDateTime(). Notice the separate answer I just posted has code that makes it work for me, but I don't understand why this code is necessary.... it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with this code that I tested and it solves the problem. It does feel like a bit of a 'hack' and I'm not sure why it's required, but it does work. It looks for fields of the structure:

```
anyField: {
   $date: {
       $numberLong: "1572318771000"
   }
}
```

and converts it into a UTCDateTime.

```
public static function fixMongoDBTimestampFields(&$record)
{
    foreach ($record as $fieldName => &$value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) || ($value instanceof Traversable))
        {
            if ( array_key_exists( '$date', $value) && is_array($value['$date']) && array_key_exists( '$numberLong', $value['$date']) )
            {
                $millisecs = $value['$date']['$numberLong'];
                $value = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($millisecs);
            }

            self::fixMongoDBTimestampFields($value);
        }
    }
    unset($value);
}
```

Comment: I would try directly `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($value)` instead of `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($value['$date']['$numberLong'])` - Of course, this works only if you know field `date_modified` represents a `Date`.